# OpenCL doesn't list Intel integrated GPU

Tags: opencl

I'm new to OpenCL and I have two graphics cards on my system 1. AMD and 2. Integrated Intel GPU. My Processor is Intel i7-3rd gen.

I have installed the latest Intel SDK openCL. And I have successfully integrated that to visual studio.

In visual studio, I get 3 platforms and it follows the below structure.

Platform 1: Intel CPU, No of devices: 1

Platform 2: AMD GPU, No of devices: 2 (Genuine Intel CPU and AMD GPU)

Platform 3: Intel CPU, No of devices: 1 (Intel (R) CPU).

OpenCL version it shows 1.2.

```
for (int j = 0; j < platforms.size(); j++) {
        auto p = platforms[j];//Change platform from 0,1 and 2
        std::vector <cl::Device> devices;
        p.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
            auto device = devices[i];
            auto vendor = device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VENDOR>();
            std::cout << vendor << std::endl;
            auto version = device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VERSION>();
        }
        std::cout << "----------------------\n";
    }
```

I'm not sure why is it not listing integrated gpu?.

Comment: I'm not positive so I'm posting a comment instead of an answer. "latest Intel SDK openCL" could mean just the CPU driver. Try installing the latest GPU driver for your integrated GPU. You might have to uninstall the CPU driver to do it (Intel is strange that way). Also, I wonder why you ended up with two Intel platforms?